# How to prevent nav from disappearing after activating-deactivating mobile button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu, navigation

This is a tricky question to phrase but I'll try my best:

If you **go to** http://msukkar.tumblr.com and resize your window (if you're using a desktop/laptop) until the hamburger menu icon appears then click on it to get the drop-down menu, click on it again to hide it. You'll find that when you resize your window back up full-width the original navigation is gone.

I'm curious as to how I can prevent this exactly. I'm adept at HTML & CSS but very new to Javascript.

The Javascript that I used is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    /* prepend menu icon */
    $('#menu_wrapper').prepend('<img id="mobile_menu" src="http://msukkar.com/wp-content/themes/pptitan/images/mobile_menu.png" alt="">');

    /* toggle nav */
    $("#mobile_menu").on("click", function () {
        $("#menu_border_wrapper").slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });

});

    });
</script>
```

The HTML for the menu is

```
<div id="menu_wrapper">

        <!-- Begin logo -->

        <a id="custom_logo" class="logo_wrapper" href="http://msukkar.com" style="font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif; letter-spacing: 1px; font-size: 14px; margin-top: 16px; ">
            MATT SUKKAR
        </a>        

        <!-- End logo -->

        <!-- Begin main nav -->
        <div id="nav_wrapper">
            <div class="nav_wrapper_inner">
                <div id="menu_border_wrapper">
                    <div class="menu-home-container">
                        <ul id="main_menu" class="nav">
                            <li id="menu-item-1235" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1235">
                                <a href="http://msukkar.tumblr.com" style="color: #ff0000">
                                    Blog
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li id="menu-item-1485" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1235">
                                <a href="http://msukkar.com/contact/">
                                    Contact
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>                  

                    <select>
                        <option selected="selected" value="">
                            - Main Menu -
                        </option>
                        <option selected="selected" value="http://msukkar.tumblr.com">
                            Blog
                        </option>
                        <option value="http://msukkar.com/contact/">
                            Contact
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I hope I explained that well enough for you all.  Thanks in advance for your help and if need be I'll try to clarify further.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem:

```
$("#menu_border_wrapper").slideToggle();
```

Which shows and hides your menu when you click the *hamburger*.

The problem is that when you are in desktop view, your entire menu is contained within `#menu_border_wrapper` and is displayed as it should. Then you resize down to mobile and click the *hamburger*. On your first click, `#menu_border_wrapper` slides down and your menu becomes visible. On your second click, `#menu_border_wrapper` slides up and your menu becomes invisible. This is fine on mobile since the hamburger icon itself isnt contained within `#menu_border_wrapper`, but when you resize the window back to desktop, the menu is gone! Remeber how on the second click the menu was sliding up and was set to `display: none`. Well now since your desktop size menu is contained **within** `#menu_border_wrapper`, it's not there anymore.

There are probably a lot of ways you can solve this. Move the actual menu buttons outside `#menu_border_wrapper` on desktop aswell, make two completely unique menues for mobile and desktop or set `#menu_border_wrapper` to `display: block !important` on desktop.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey Magnus, thanks for stepping up.  I'm putting your advice into practice right now and have complete faith that one of your suggestions will come out working fine. However, if you have the time, I'm wondering how the original website template (http://msukkar.com) is accomplishing this task without getting the _glitch_, what do you think?

Comment: If this is in fact the original template, http://msukkar.com/, it's not working either.